# Sinon: spy on jquery function call

Tags: jquery, jasmine, sinon

How can I check if

```
$("#myElement").change();
```

is called on?

I've tried

```
spy = sinon.spy($("#myElement"), "change");
```

And then

```
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "override" jquery's change function by holding a reference to it, then replacing the original reference with you own function. After your new function completes, make sure the original function is called with the correct context (i.e. *this*) by calling it through function.apply(), like this:

```
var oldChange = $.fn.change; 
$.fn.change = function(args) { 
  console.log("change triggered", args); 
  oldChange.apply(this,args); };
}
```

Not sure if this is considered the best practice, though. Anyone else care to weigh in on this?